# Java file deletion

Tags: java, file, delete-file

I have this as my code:

```
      public static void ResetAccount() 
      { 
          System.gc();
          try  
          {    
              File f= new File("User.json");
              f.exists();
              if(f.delete())
              {  
                  System.out.println(f.getName() + " deleted");
              }  
              else  
              {
                  System.out.println("failed");  
              }  
          }  
          catch(Exception e)  
          {  
              e.printStackTrace();  
          }   
          UI.LoginScreen();
      }
}
```

I want to delete the file 'User.json'. How can I do this?
I tried several ways already but i just cant get it deleted.

Comment: I recommend printing the return value of `f.exists();` to see if the file actually exists. I reckon you're running your program from a different directory to your `User.json` file

Comment: 1. log `f.getAbsolutePath()` You are most likely in a different directory. 2. `f.exists()` result is ignored. 3. Avoid calling `System.gc()` 4. try catching something more specific than `Exception` 5. Extract deleting json to a separate method.

Comment: java.io.File is a very old class.  Do not use it.  Use [Files.deleteIfExists](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#deleteIfExists(java.nio.file.Path))(Path.of("User.json")) instead.  That method, unlike the File class, will provide a useful and informative exception if it fails.  And, like Lesiak said, don’t call System.gc().  The JVM’s garbage collection is already very efficient and doesn’t need your help.

Answer (score 1):

This code is working fine. When you are deleting the file, I would recommend putting the complete path where you expect the file to be. In this case though, your User.json file needs to be present inside your project and not inside your package as shared in the image.
[image]

Using your shared code, it deletes the file.

Comment: saddly that doesnt work, i tried that and it still couldnt delete the file.

Comment: if possible, please share your project structure